# About NVIDIA drivers not working for Ubuntu 20.04 GTX 1650

Tags: nvidia, ubuntu-20.04

I have installed NVIDIA driver (using Software and updates) for my UBUNTU 20.04 machine running on Dell G3. After installation i noticed settings in NVIDIA X Server as "NVIDIA on demand" but in about pc it shows as "Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics (CML GT2)" in graphics . I have restarted the system many times but it is of no use . My systems boots slower now after installing the NVIDIA driver. I want to use my GTX 1650 in my ubuntu 20.04. Please give any suggestions.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqaIh.png)

Comment: You have GPU switching, specifically [NVIDIA Optimus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus). Its use on Linux can be summed up as “it’s complicated”.

Answer (score 0):

If not THE answer, at least a tip towards it:

hit the Super key (Win-key) and start typing `additional drivers`, quite early you will see a "green" icon; either click on it, or if there are more than one icon select it using the arrow keys - and press enter.

You should see something similar to the image below i.e. a set of nVidia drivers

- IF you have `[x] Canonical partners` (selected!) under `/Other software\`.

If none of the nvidia-items is selected; do select one, maybe start with the highest numbered
***(not any of the `server` -designated for a non-server, i assume)***
and allow it to finish install, then reboot and check Settings/About and try it out.
If you detect any anomalies; then select another...

*For what it is worth; 515 did not "work" **for me** as i tried it; GTX 1660 TI Mobile*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the Nvidia X Server settings opens correctly then you have the Nvidia drivers installed and loaded.

"NVIDIA on demand" is the profile that allows (or, better said, it should allow) toggling the graphics depending on the demand of the software running, similar of what the Windows drivers provide. **In this mode, just like with Windows, is supposed to run with the iGPU (Intel) most of the time, only switching to the dGPU (Nvidia) if there's software that needs it.**

If you want to run with Nvidia all the time then you must select the "High performance" profile and reboot.